# Difference between stateNotiferProvider and notifierProvider in Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

What is the difference between notifier provider and state notifier provider in flutter riverpod and when to use them.

In the riverpod docs they ask to use notifier provider instead of state notifier provider. I need help to determine when to use each of them in my project.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Notifier` is a replacement of `StateNotifier` + `ChangeNotifier`.

It's a more flexible approach better fit for Riverpod and more in line with how to use Riverpod. Use `Notifier` or `AsyncNotifier` in favor of `StateNotifier`/`ChangeNotifier`.

Comment: I wonder why we can modify state of Notifier from outside. It look dangerous. What was the reason to allow it?

Comment: @Rémi can you please explain your answer in more details why AsyncNotifier is more favorable than StateNotifier and what's the difference between both?

Comment: @FlutterSupabase Notifiers are only modifiable from outside if they expose a way to do so. Otherwise "state" is protected

Comment: @Nicks AsyncNotifier is newer. StateNotifier predates Riverpod. AsyncNotifier is more in-line with Riverpod and makes dealing with fetching asynchronous data much simpler, as it removed the need for error/loading handling